# Instantiating a Class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following class structure

```
module ChartingServices {

export class ChartOptions {
    options: myOptions;
    title: string;
}

export interface myOptions {
    colors: string[];
    legend: myLegend;
    type: string;
}

export interface myLegend{
    enabled: boolean;
    labelFormatter: string;
}
}
```

and I create an instance of it in the usual way:-

```
var chartOptions = new ChartingServices.ChartOptions();
```

I can set the property chartOptions.title with no problem at all.

However, I cannot get to the property chartOptions.myOptions.type and get an error about not being able to read property 'type' of undefined.

Bearing in mind I have loads of classes, do I need to create an instance of each one to set / read properties. What can I do to get the code to work?

Answer (score 11):

The first problem is that `.myOptions` does not exist on `chartOptions` - you want `options`. You should capitalize all of your types: `MyOptions`, `MyLegend`, so that you do not confuse them with property names.

The second problem is that although you instantiate a new `ChartOptions`:

```
var chartOptions = new ChartOptions();
```

...its `options` property isn't actually set to anything, and is therefore undefined. You need to set it either using a statement right after instantiation:

```
chartOptions.options = {type: "foo", ...other non-optional properties here}
```

Or in the constructor of `ChartOptions`, or via:

```
options: MyOptions = {type: "foo", ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript behaves similarly to the underlying JavaScript (and most other languages) in terms of object instantiation: all fields are initialised to `undefined` unless you override it with a value.

Also, there's no way to instantiate an interface. Instead you have to supply an object matching the signature. If you don't want to supply all the fields at the beginning, you can mark the fields in the interface with `?` so they become optional, then you can do

```
export class ChartOptions {
    options: myOptions = {};
...
```

Comment: I've done that and it seems to work fine. But referencing my original code, there is an issue with doing that on legend: myLegend because you can't initialise an interface member.

Would I need to change myLegend from an interface to a class?

Comment: Your options for `myLegend` are the same as `myOptions`. Either turn it into a class and construct a new instance every time or make all the fields optional and supply `{}` as the initial value (like what I suggested for `myOptions` above).

Comment: It would seem that you can do this on a class but myLegend is on an interface so putting legend: myLegend = {} does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i only needed a check to specific classes. I used 'constructor.name', which crashed on production mode.

I used it in a switch-statement with error on default

```
switch (constructorInput.constructor.name) {
        case 'A':
            // do something
            break;
        case 'B':
            // do something
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error(constructorInput.constructor.name + ' is no valid Type');
    }
```

So, i already could change it to instanceof

```
if (constructorInput instanceof A) {
        // do something
    } else if (constructorInput instanceof B) {
        // do something
    } else {
        throw new Error('no valid Type');
    }
```

This is working at production and development.